# How to add additional shipping charge after table rate?

Tags: magento-enterprise, shipping-methods

I'm using Magento default Table Rates - Weight v/s Destination.

Products will be volumetric/weight based. Example :- X meters/X kg.

After table rates is calculated.

If cart total weight/volume who ever exceeds up to X level, i have to add additional weight also then it's rate.

Can i achieve this using magento default functionality or need to do customization in shipping method?

Comment: In magento flate rate method by default not provided Weight v/s Destination functionality

But Table Rates shipping method is provided Weight v/s Destination functionality

Comment: have you used table rate shipping method?

Comment: it is achieve default functionality

Comment: After calculation of table rates, if suppose weight is 20kg, then we have to add it in Big Box, so we have to add that weight as well. If its 40kg, then Big Container, so add that weight as well & respective rates.

Comment: have you needed additional weight & rate after order placed or before?

Comment: Before order placed, because that extra shipping cost will be added in Grand Total

Comment: When you add extra weight or shipping cost? Have you needed dynamic?

Comment: Yes it should be dynamic

Comment: have you uploaded table rate csv file form admin side : System -> Shipping methods  ?

Comment: Yes. This is extra calculation which should trigger after table rates calculation done

Comment: so need to change in code